# Twitter Bootstrap / Landscape mode issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and Wordpress in order to make a portfolio site. I've not modified Bootstrap core CSS (bootstrap.css and responsive.css) but I've added a custom CSS with some adjustments.

In this case, I've created a 2 column gallery with 6 thumbs using this as my custom CSS:

```
    #featured-content {

    padding: 3.125%;

}


#featured-content article.span4 {

    float: left;
    width: 48.33333333333333%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

}

#featured-content article.span4.even {

    margin-left: 3.33333333333334%;

}


#featured-content article.span4 img {

    min-width: 100%;

}
```

This works like a charm in portrait mode:

[image: Portrait mode]

However, in landscape mode I am getting this ugly bug in the last 2 images:

[image: Landscape Mode]

Images are the same size so that's not the problem. Also, all my CSS is based on percentages so once the user switches to landscape it should scale while still keeping proportions, right?

Also, this happens in the last 2 images, which is totally weird.

Thanks!

Comment: you have to mention different css for landscape too... you can change with in bootstrap-responsive.css for this...

Comment: Thanks @SaurabhLP but why should I do this if my custom CSS is based on percentages? Everything should scale properly, no matter the screen orientation. Also, the bug happens on the last 2 thumbnails, the first 4 thumbnails are properly aligned in landscape mode.

Comment: it is because the ratio between the container width, padding and margin is not adequate for different screens sizes, twitter bootstrap uses some css for responsive ui also, like landscapes/portrait for mobile/tablet etc...